# Why is my imported ES6 module not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, webpack, ecmascript-6

I' building a WordPress plugin and I use Webpack to bundle my JavaScript code. Everything worked, until I wanted to implement some toast notifications with the jquery-toast-plugin.
The following code, leads to a `Uncaught TypeError: $.toast is not a function` in the browser console:

```
import 'jquery-validation';
import toastr from 'toastr';
import 'jquery-toast-plugin';

class ManualOrder {
    constructor() {
        this.host = 'https://dev7.digitaldocks.de/';

        $.toast({
            heading: 'Welcome to my website',
            text: 'test',
            showHideTransition: 'slide',
            icon: 'success'
        });
```

In addition this is my webpack config, where I actualy resolve $ and jQuery. jQuery is working aside from the $.toast():

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require('css-minimizer-webpack-plugin');
const IgnoreEmitPlugin = require('ignore-emit-webpack-plugin');

const config = {
    entry: {
        strayfe_fbsb_bundled: './public/assets/src/js/index.js',
        strayfe_main: './public/assets/src/scss/main.scss',
    },

    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public/assets/dist'),
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader',
                ],
            },
        ],
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: require.resolve('jquery'),
            jquery: require.resolve('jquery'),
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: ({ chunk }) => (chunk.name === 'main_css' ? 'strayfe_main.css' : '[name].css'),
        }),
        new IgnoreEmitPlugin(['strayfe_main.js']),
    ],

    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [
            new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
        ],
    },
};

module.exports = config;
```

Now what's super odd to me, is that this codeblock is working inside WordPress and the toast notification is executed successfully:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Demo - Toast Plugin</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="module">
        import 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-toast-plugin/1.3.2/jquery.toast.min.js';
            $.toast({
                heading: 'Welcome to my website',
                text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste, quibusdam.',
                showHideTransition: 'slide',
                icon: 'success'
            })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I guess I got something mixed up with the import logic or something? I would be so happy if you could help me.